# Calling a GET REST API in golang with a path variable

Tags: go

I am trying Golang for the first time. I am trying to call a GET REST API which has a path variable. I am using net/http for that. I am trying like below but no luck so far. I need to know how I can use the path variable and pass the variable from the code. Any help or code example would be highly appreciated.

This does not seem to work:

```golang
http.Get("http://127.19.0.1:8080/student/:id")
```

Comment: There's no such thing as path variables in HTTP. It's just a string you need to put together.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @Adrian I tried to find the syntax where net/http will accept a variable in the URL which will be passed by the user. As I did not find anything, I asked the question here. It seems that the answer provided here is working. If you know a better solution, you can provide it please.

Comment: If I understand your problem, I don't think there's any special way to handle a variable in the http.Get() method. You could simply use fmt.Sprintf("http://127.19.0.1/student/%s", user.ID) to format the request string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about

```
http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("http://127.19.0.1:8080/student/%s", id)
```

?